# Drag and Drop files from desktop to web application using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I want to drop the file in a folder so that the file will be get picked up by my web application.

Comment: You can't do it with Selenium. Maybe with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: Can you help me finding the proper link for the same?

Comment: Guy - can we automate the desktop application using AutoIt ? The application is third party and using it with our web application.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unfortunately, WebDriver only perform operation on the browser's webElement like textbox, drop-down etc. and can't access anything outside of it. If you want to drag'n'drop then you'll have to use Robot or any other tools which have methods and jars that support that functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to drop a file in folder on local so that it will get picked up by web application?

Comment: Ok. i will find for you